# How to create for-loop that does not overwrite the output xml?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, pdf, xml-parsing

I have a huge directory of pdf files that I need to parse into xml files. Those xml files would then need to be converted into an `xlsx` (using a pandas `df`). I have written the code for the latter and it is working, but I am stuck on figuring out this `for`-loop.

Here is the loop:

```
import io
from xml.etree import ElementTree
from pprint import pprint
import os
from os.path import isfile, join
import pandas as pd
from os import listdir

directory = '/jupyter/pdf_script_test/pdf_files_test'
i = 1
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    print(filename)
    if filename.endswith('.pdf'):
        pathname = os.path.join(directory, filename)
        # attempt to assign variable name
        filename = 'new_output%s' %i
        os.system('dumppdf.py -a' + pathname + '>new_output.xml')
        i = i + 1
else:
    print('invalid pdf file')
```

So I can see pretty quickly that each time the loop iterates, it will overwrite `"new_output.xml"` with the previous pdf file. I was trying to find a way to maybe assign a variable name or maybe create a nested loop that would help fix the problem. My biggest hang up is how to incorporate `dumppdf.py` into this loop.

Maybe a nested loop that looks something like this:

```
# code from above here...
data = os.system('dumppdf.py -a' + pathname) # etc..
with open('data' + str(i) + '.xml', 'w') as outfile:
    f.write()
```

Comment: Use `>>new_output.xml` (note the two brackets instead of one) in your `os.system` call, that way it will append instead of overwrite that file. It's a pretty weird way of doing things though to call another python script using os.system.

Comment: Thanks, that stopped the output from overwriting itself. I agree it is a weird set-up, but I am unsure of how else to incorporate dumppdf.py in this instance. Its the only thing that worked for converting the pdf files into xml format successfully. PyPDF2 and others failed to work since they left all the filled form areas blank..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I ended up solving my problem:

```
import io
from xml.etree import ElementTree
from pprint import pprint
import os
from os.path import isfile, join
import pandas as pd
from os import listdir

directory = '/jupyter/pdf_script_test/pdf_files_test/'
patient_number = 1 #variable name 

#loop over pdf files and write a new .xml for each pdf file. 
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    print(filename)
    if filename.endswith(".pdf"):
        pathname = os.path.join(directory, filename)
#Run dumppdf.py on the pdf file and write the .xml using the assigned variable
        data = os.system('dumppdf.py -a ' + pathname + ' > ' + str(patient_number) + '.xml') 
        patient_number = patient_number + 1
 
    else:
        print("invaild pdf file")
```